# Inverting a system of equations

Tags: linear-algebra

$$a_{out} = a\ \mathrm{\cos}(\theta) + i b\ \mathrm{\sin}(\theta)$$

$$b_{out} = b\ \mathrm{\cos}(\theta) + i a\ \mathrm{\sin}(\theta)$$

What procedure would one use to invert this to get:

$$a = a_{out}\ \mathrm{\cos}(\theta) - i b_{out}\ \mathrm{\sin}(\theta)$$

$$b = b_{out}\ \mathrm{\cos}(\theta) - i a_{out}\ \mathrm{\sin}(\theta)$$

I can't seem to reproduce this result by solving the first system. Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: Normally for a rotation, one of the $\sin$ terms in each equation has a minus sign.  Is this pair really what you want?  It can be solved.

Answer (score 2):

This is a [system of linear equations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_of_linear_equations).  If we add and subtract them we get $$a_{out}+b_{out}=(a+b)(\cos \theta + i \sin \theta)\\a_{out}-b_{out}=(a-b)(\cos \theta - i \sin \theta)\\a+b=\frac {a_{out}+b_{out}}{\cos \theta + i \sin \theta}\\a-b=\frac {a_{out}-b_{out}}{\cos \theta - i \sin \theta}\\a=\frac 12\left(\frac {a_{out}+b_{out}}{\cos \theta + i \sin \theta}+\frac {a_{out}-b_{out}}{\cos \theta - i \sin \theta}\right)\\a=\frac 12(a_{out}+b_{out})(\cos \theta -i\sin \theta)+\frac 12(a_{out}-b_{out})(\cos \theta +i\sin \theta)\\a=a_{out}\cos \theta -b_{out}i\sin \theta\\b=-a_{out}i\sin \theta +b_{out}\cos \theta$$

Answer (score 1):

The matrix that appears in the second set of equations is the inverse of the one in the first set. You can easily confirm this by multiplying them together, which will give you a $2 \times 2$ identity matrix.

Solving by Cramer's rule or elimination will give you a bit of a mess, but you could probably work through all the algebra and get the same result.

Answer (score 1):

$\begin{pmatrix}a_{out}\\b_{out}\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}cos(\theta)&isin(\theta)\\isin(\theta)&cos(\theta)\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}a\\b\end{pmatrix}$so

$\begin{pmatrix}a\\b\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}cos(\theta)&isin(\theta)\\isin(\theta)&cos(\theta)\end{pmatrix}^{-1}\begin{pmatrix}a_{out}\\b_{out}\end{pmatrix}$so

$\begin{pmatrix}a\\b\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}cos(\theta)&-isin(\theta)\\-isin(\theta)&cos(\theta)\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}a_{out}\\b_{out}\end{pmatrix}$